# Navegar nos registros da query com PHP PDO

Tags: php, query, pdo

Sempre trabalhei com conexões ASP utilizando ADODB e navegar nos regristros que a query me retornava não era um problema pois haviam:

```
<%
rs.movenext //anda para proxima linha do retorno da query
rs.moveprevious //anda para linha anterior do retorno da query
rs.movefirst //anda para a primeira linha do retorno da query
rs.movelast //anda para a ultima linha do retorno da query
%>
```

*mais informações sobre esses comandos [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_recordset.asp).*

Estou com dificuldades para navegar nos registros da minha query em PHP utilizando PDO. Não encontrei algo que seja equivalente a esses comandos citados acima por exemplo.

Digamos que eu tenha um `foreach` para percorrer uma query, mas dentro de cada laço preciso verificar se o próximo registro é o ultimo registro para adicionar alguma informação a mais neste laço atual... como fazer?

```
<?php
$sql = "Select * From Tabela";
$sql = $db->prepare($sql_pai);
$sql->execute();
if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
   foreach($sql as $rs){
      echo $rs["nome"];
      //VERIFICAR SE O PROXIMO É O ULTIMO PARA ADICIONAR MAIS INFO
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: No `PDO` tem o `lastInsertId()` veja -> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

o método `PDOStatement::fetch()` recebe como segundo parâmetro a orientação do cursor, com o valor de uma das constantes `PDO::FETCH_ORI_*`. Esses parâmetros só são válidos se o cursor de `PDOStatement` for criado passando o atributo `PDO::ATTR_CURSOR` com valor `PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL`.

Dessa forma você pode navegar utilizando da seguinte forma

```
$sql = "Select * From Tabela";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql, array(
    PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL,
));
$statement->execute();
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT);  // retorna próximo
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_PRIOR); // retorna anterior
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST); // retorna primeiro
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);  // retorna último
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS, $n); // retorna posição $n
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_REL, $n); // retorna posição $n relativa à posição atual
```

Veja mais detalhes na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters) e em [constantes pré-definidas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.constants.php).

Com as funções apresentadas você pode criar um *loop* para resolver o seu problema.

Nota: utilizei `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` pois é o método padrão, mas você pode alterar para o modo utilizado em seu projeto.

Answer (score 0):

No PHP você pode navegar por um array de forma parecida com as seguintes funções:

- [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.current.php) - Retorna o elemento corrente em um array
- [`each()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.each.php) - Retorna o par chave/valor corrente de um array e avança o seu cursor
- [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.reset.php) - Faz o ponteiro interno de um array apontar para o seu primeiro elemento
- [`prev()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.prev.php) - Retrocede o ponteiro interno de um array
- [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.next.php) - Avança o ponteiro interno de um array
- [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.end.php) - Faz o ponteiro interno de um array apontar para o seu último elemento

Vale lembrar que isso funciona só para a navegação com o Array. O PDO é somente uma camada de abstração para a **conexão** com o banco.

Talvez o que você esteja procurando é algum [ORM](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=php%20ORM&oq=php%20ORM&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1096j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica do array. Mas ainda fico na dúvida se o PDO não teria algo mais "nativo" pra não precisar recorrer a isso.